# Add and remove the bootstrap typeahead dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can we add and remove the bootstrap typeahead dynamically.

Means in some case I need to give the typeahaed functionality to one textbox and need to remove this functionality for the same input box in another case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the

```
 $('.typeahead').removeClass('dropdown-menu');
```

and

```
$('.typeahead').addClass('dropdown-menu');
```

to hide show that drop-down suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

I know I'm late to the party, below will remove instead of just hide.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('destroy');
```

Comment: +1 This helps when using the same field to be populated (for instance in a popup) The field is not cleared automatically, this way the `typeahead` is silently removed without disturbing the field and or its content. This is also the correct way to remove the typeahead

Comment: this doesn't work for my application. it gets rid of data in completely different areas. but I do re-use my typeahead so I need some way to refresh the data it pulls.

Comment: Not sure why it would not work for you.  Are you using remote or prefetch?  Are you using IE? IE sometimes has caching issues. If it is IE you may try adding `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` to fix IE.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You can. It's quite easy with using jquery method [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

For example:

```
$('.typehead').typehead();
//and then you can dynamically unbind this plugin
$('.typehead').unbind();
```

Comment: Thankx! for your time. But I can not use unbind. But I have used 
$('.typeahead').removeClass('dropdown-menu'); 
This method to hide drop-down. and add this class again

Comment: Use this method with caution, as this will remove all event listeners from the selected DOM element, rather than just the typeahead listeners (which are on `blur`, `focus`, `input`, and `keydown`).

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a different (and hackier) solution because I'm changing the typeahead data each time I bind it and couldn't get the other answers to work. I'll leave it here in case anyone needs it.

**Remove Typeahead**

```
var parent = $('.typeahead').parent();
var html = parent.html();
$('.typeahead).remove();
parent.html(html);
```

**Add Typeahead**

```
$('.typehead').typehead();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me.

```
var typeaheadEle = $('#myTypeahead').data('typeahead');
 if (typeaheadEle) {typeaheadEle.source = [];}
```

where *myTypeahead* is id of the input element.

Comment: This is the best method to use for Bootstrap v2.3.2, imo.

Answer (score 0):

I found `$('.some-typeahead-parent .tt-dropdown-menu').hide();` to work the best for multiple data set typeahead.